# Why is CreateFile failing to open a file across a network share?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, file-io

I wrote a small program which frequently opens small, user text files and until now haven't encountered any problems with read/write access or any sorts of conflict.  The files are selected in another piece of software which I have no control over, and are passed to me as a string.

When attempting to open a file from a mapped network drive I am getting a "The system cannot find the path specified" error (GetLastError() = 3).

The call is shown below, `*iNCfileName = "z:\\Validation\\Sample Files\\1_1-4 120MM.CC"`, where Z: is a mapped folder on our domain.

```
iNCfile = CreateFile( iNCfileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
if ( iNCfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
{
    string msg; // lots of better ways to get this printed ... but ...
    dw = GetLastError();
    msg = iNCfileName;
    msg += ": ";
    msg += _com_error(dw).ErrorMessage();
    print_error(dw , (char*)msg.c_str() );
    return 102;
}
```

The file opens from my program if I copy it to the local hard drive.  It also opens in notepad from the mapped drive.

Could this be a problem between the "Z:\whatever.txt" mapped representation and the true file name (\mydomain\Validation\S....??)?

If so, how can I convert from one to the other in a programmatic way (assume I won't know the domain/share names ahead of time)?

If it makes any difference I use VS2010 and the application executes on a Win XP machine.

Related: [my follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9705535/759749)

Comment: Repeat after me: "I will use `GetLastError()`."

Comment: Call GetLastError() and get the specific failure value..

Comment: Apart from `GetLastError()`, can you show population of `iNCfileName`.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes, it's clear that I should have.

Comment: @hmjd Updated with both pieces of information.

Comment: I don't see how `inCfileName` is populated?

Comment: @hmjd It's a string passed to my program, in this instance the string is "z:\Validation\Sample Files\1_1-4 120MM.CC"

Comment: Does the code work for files from things other than mapped drives?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, local hard drive, usb drives directly connected ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this before. When using a path like `\\DOMAIN\PATH\FILE.TXT` I had to first call `WNetAddConnection2()`.

Here is my code (of course you can exclude the NULL members):

```
NETRESOURCE nr = {0}; //new structure for network resource
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY; //generic resource (any type allowed)
nr.lpLocalName = NULL; //does not use a device
nr.lpRemoteName = "\\\\DOMAIN\\PATH\\FOLDER"; //For me, this pointed to an account's documents folder, and from there I could use a subfolder
nr.lpProvider = NULL; //no provider

DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2 (&nr, NULL, NULL, CONNECT_TEMPORARY); //add connection
```

Don't forget the header and library.

Comment: Did you find a way to programatically determine if the file was local or remote or did you know that you were always accessing a remote file?

Comment: I was actually testing out something that created and wrote to files on my account from another person's account. Running it on my own account produced the exact same results though. One thing to note is that the account running the program must have correct access rights to the destination.

Comment: Yes, I can access the files through Windows Explorer, edit them, whatever I want manually.

Comment: I would imagine replacing the `\\x\y\z` format with `X:\y\z` format for a drive being `net use`d would produce the same result as well.

Comment: If you end up needing the `\\x\y\z` format, do you have access to see the command used in order to map the `Z:` drive? If so, you can look through and find what it is being mapped to in there.

Comment: No, I don't, and since my solution is going to be deployed in a variety of environments I don't have much control.  I'm still working on resolving this, I haven't forgotten to accept/etc

Comment: Well, I'll test it out with this network when I can and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: I'm still having some issues but I'm going to open a new question on it.

Comment: Ok, it's March Break at the moment and I need the school to test it out so I'll let you know after the break's done if anything seems astray.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue; trying to create a file using API `CreateFileW` under a mapped drive ( `Z:\folder` ) did not worked; howerver, after researching this subject i tried to create the file using the real path (  `\\Shared_computer_name\folder\` ) immediately worked successfully.

Now I have to work a function to retrieve the real name of a mapped drive, to use it when necessary... just found `WNetGetUniversalName`, have to make it to work.