# How can I resolve a ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME error in a call to WNetAddConnection2?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, file-io

I am still trying to resolve a problem I'm having, [the first part of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9587756/759749) was that I apparently need to call WNetAddConnection2 in order to use CreateFile to open a file across a network share.

Having done so, I am now receiving an ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME return from the WNet...2 call.

The remote resource is a mapped network folder on a windows network (the client, where we are, is windows xp).  The network resource *should* be connected on startup, but it'd probably be bad to assume that, of course.  The folder maps to local `Z:`.  I am able to access, read, write and delete files from the destination folder on the machine using Explorer.

```
HANDLE initFile ( LPCTSTR iNCfileName ) {
    DWORD dw;
    HANDLE fHandle=NULL;

    NETRESOURCE nr = {0}; //new structure for network resource
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY; //generic resource (any type allowed)
    nr.lpLocalName = NULL; //does not use a device
    // typical iNCfileName is std::string a="Z:\\Documents\\somefile.txt".c_str()
    nr.lpRemoteName = (char*)iNCfileName;
    //"\\\\DOMAIN\\PATH\\FOLDER"; 
    nr.lpProvider = NULL; //no provider

    // CONNECT_CURRENT_MEDIA ??
    DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2 (&nr, NULL, NULL, CONNECT_TEMPORARY); 

    //...

    return fHandle;
}
```

I **think** that the problem is I cannot use `Z:\Documents\somefile.txt` but rather should be using the \\DOMAIN\PATH\FOLDER notation.  If that's the case, how do I programatically obtain that information so that I can provide it as input?  Did I misunderstand the orignal answerer that I can convert the file name to `\\\\Z\\Documents\\somefile.txt`?  If so is there a resource to perform this or should I parse the string myself?

Comment: Casting to (char*) just stops the compiler from telling you are doing it wrong.  Remove the cast.  If the compiler complains again, actually convert the string.  Or use UNICODE consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about why it's not working.  You are passing a local file name (e.g. `Z:\Documents\somefile.txt`) when you should be passing a share name (e.g. `\\myserver\sharename`).

If the share is already connected to `Z:` then you don't need to call `WNetAddConnection2`.

If the share is not already connected to `Z:` then there's no way you can automatically convert `Z:\Documents\somefile.txt` to a remote name because Windows has no idea what `Z:` represents.

If the share might not be connected then your program needs to know in advance what share `Z:` is supposed to connect to and make the connection itself.  You can either connect the share to `Z:` and use the existing path, or connect it with no drive letter and adjust the path yourself; you just need to replace the `Z:\` with `\\myserver\sharename\`.

Comment: The motivation to add WNetAddConnection2 (see linked question) was that CreateFile was returning a "The system cannot find the path specified" error with the Z: path/filename.  If the same file is local there's no problem.  The Z: path/filename was mapped and accessible from explorer without error.  So with all that said, if I don't need WNetAddConnection2, how do I resolve the original problem?

Comment: If Windows does know what the share means, how can I retrieve that information?  (Short of putting in a configuration option to have the user tell me what their network server and share names are, which is one more thing to break later)

Comment: My code is running in a user mode windows thread started by a dll loaded by a kernel mode application.  The kernel mode application is user loaded and not a service.

Comment: Ah!  Unless they are created in session 0, network connections are per-session.  I guess Z: is mapped in an interactive session, but this won't be visible to your code which (I guess) is running in session 0.  Attempting to discover what Z: is mapped to would be a bit of a hack: there might be more than one interactive session with Z: mapped to different network shares in each session.  If your software has a component that runs in the interactive session and communicates with your session 0 component then that should do the mapping.  If not, an outline of your architecture would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help... since it's getting overly complex I've required the components that call this subsystem move the files onto the local drive (trivial from that side of the code).