# How to resolve Error-487 during WNetAddConnection in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, connection

I have been trying to connect remote PC with known Credentials but variable **lon**(refer below code) is showing Error-487.

Code:

```
Private Declare Function WNetAddConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetAddConnection2A" ( ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Long

Private Declare Function WNetCancelConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetCancelConnection2A" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal fForce As Integer) As Long

Private Structure NETRESOURCE

    Dim dwType As Long
    Dim lpRemoteName As String

End Structure

Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK = &H1

Private Sub ConnectToPC()

    Dim networkResource As New NETRESOURCE
    Dim lon As Long

    With networkResource

        .dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
        .lpRemoteName = "\\192.168.1.1"

    End With

    lon = WNetAddConnection2(networkResource, "123", "ADMIN", 0)

         msgbox(lon)

    lon = WNetCancelConnection2("\\192.168.1.1", 0, 1)

         msgbox(lon)

End Sub
```

**Tried Below thing but it didn't serve my purpose** 
 - Change type from Integer to Int32/Int64

I have been working on this issue for last two days but couldn't gain any success. Can anybody tell me what went wrong with code? Any help will be highly Appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that your API declarations are for VB.NET and not VB6? Whenever such a declaration uses `Long` it's a red flag. Most API functions use 32-bit numbers which meant `Long` in VB6 but means `Integer` in VB.NET.

Comment: I think that's the likely issue. Here's the relevant [pinvoke.net page](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.wnetaddconnection2).

Comment: Actually I used VB6 code with little modification in API function to cater my requirement in VB.NET such as Added ByRef to NETRESOURCE parameter and changed 'Type' to 'Structure' as it is not supported in .NET. But still Error is inevitable. Can you suggest possible fix?@jmcilhinney

Comment: I already told you what the issue is.

Comment: Still having issues? Check out the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706247/10216583) Also, it'll be useful if you mention the OS of both machines.

Comment: Hi @JQSOFT. yes I am still having an Issue. both machines are having Windows 10 installed. But I don't understand where am I making mistake with this code because similar code is quite flawlessly executed in VB6 without an error.