# CreateFile failed with ACCESS_DENIED for network drive on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i'm having issue with the windows CreateFile function for network drive on Windows 7 (**it works perfectly on XP**).

before calling Createfile, i mount the network drive  :

```
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
nr.lpLocalName = NULL;// to let windows auto choose the local letter
nr.lpRemoteName = strTemp.GetBuffer(); // example: \\myhost\mySharedFolder
nr.lpProvider = NULL;

TCHAR AccessName [MAX_PATH];            
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(AccessName);
ZeroMemory(AccessName,dwSize);
dwResult = WNetUseConnection(NULL
        ,&nr
        ,(LPSTR) NULL
        ,(LPSTR) NULL
        ,CONNECT_REDIRECT
        ,AccessName
        ,&dwSize
        ,&dwRet);
```

this works well. I see the mounted drive in Win7 explorer, it's shared with total control from the host side, i can create, edit, delete files ...no issue here.

Then i want to get devices information using CreateFiles :

```
TCHAR szVolumeName[8];
sprintf(szVolumeName, "\\\\.\\%s", szDrive);  //for example \\.\z:
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(szVolumeName,
            0/*GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE*/,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);
```

Note the path formating '\\.\driveLetter: '  (according to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027/en-us)).   I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587756/why-is-createfile-failing-to-open-a-file-across-a-network-share) but it everything fails harder if i format the string like " z:" or "z:\"

Also note the '0' for the acces right mask, which allow, according to [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If this parameter is zero, the application can query certain metadata such as file, directory, or device attributes without accessing that file or device, even if GENERIC_READ access would have been denied.

And despite all this, it fails with a **getLastError() = 5**  on Win7 (as mentioned earlier, it works on XP)
Whereas it works for local drives (even removable devices)

I have the same behabiour running the app under a standard user account or an admin account and "runnin as admin" thingy

So, question :  Is this normal behaviour, what could I do about it ? Why does it works for local drive even when run as standard user ?

Comment: error code 5 is "Access is denied".  But I'm guessing you already knew that.  What are you trying to do anyway by opening the network drive letter?  There may be other APIs that do what you want.

Comment: UAC elevation is normally required.

Comment: @selbie, indeed i knew it ,as mentioned in the tittle ^_^. And i use this to get a valid handle for following calls to DeviceIOControl

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I wrapped the second block in a simple `main` and it worked on XP and 7 as both a normal user and as an admin, for local drives and existing mapped drives. If you make a complete compilable example that creates the mapping itself (prompting for password), I'd be happy to try that.

Comment: One way I was able to reproduce the `CreateFile` error 5 was by trying it against a VMWare shared folder mapped drive (although it failed on both XP and 7). What kind of server are you making the connection to, and are you connecting to the exact same share in both the XP and 7 cases?

Comment: Surely it depends massively on the type of network volume, how you connect to it, how it is secured etc.